# Running footer "element(footer)" in paged media appear only in last page

Tags: css, footer, css-paged-media

I am working on a paged css with running footers inside the margin boxes. Everything worked almost as expected until I was asked by the graphic designer to make a part of the footer bold and I could no longer use content:"text" for the footers.

I have decided to use content:element(footer) and I have added the footer at the end of my dynamically created html page, but it is only displayed on the last page. I have searched but everybody seems to have the opposite problem (they want it only on the last page and have it on all) or are not using CSS3 printed media styles.

```
    @page {
    size: 170mm 240mm;
    margin:  23.5mm 27.5mm 23mm;

    @bottom-center {
       content: element(footer);
        font: normal 8pt MyLucida;
    }
    }
    footer {position: running(footer);
  font-family: MyLucida;
  font-size: 8pt;}
```

HTML

```
    <footer>
    My Journal Issue [<b>000</b>] Month Year
    </footer>
```

I was expecting to find the footer on evey page but blank pages, but it only appear on the last page, in the right position inside the box. Changing "position: running(footer)" to "position: absolute" did not change anything. It seems that the footer is added only once at the end and not repeated at all. I had to repeat the style else it was not applying it. The html is for printing only, and it is generated from db datas. My pdf converter is PrinceXML.
I hope it makes sense!

Comment: Maybe its not the CSS but the way you dynamically generated the pages? Have you inspected the HTML to see if the footer exists. Maybe create a code snippet of some static html pages using your same CSS and see if the footer is appearing in the desired position on at least 2 or more pages, if it does then its the way your generating your footer. Also in my opinion the whole point to these at-rules were to essentially position things for you. hene "top-center".. "bottom-center"... take out that position property on the footer element .

Answer (score 19):

I figured it out myself: the problem was I had included the footer at the end of the file after all the content. If I just include it at the beginning it is repeated every page as supposed.
I moved the footer at the beginning of the body and now it works!

Comment: maybe look into what i stated though in my comment in regards to forcing the position on your footer element when essentially your using the `@bottom-center at-rule`  specifically for position. Its just good practice not to overwrite what CSS3 handles for you.

Comment: This is because Prince doesn't create the footer flow until it actually reads the footer HTML code. As you noted, the footer HTML should be at the beginning of the document. At DocRaptor, we've run into a lot of tricky Prince footer and header issues and documented them here: http://help.docraptor.com/pdf-styling-and-troubleshooting/advanced-topics/headers-footers-for-pdfs.

Comment: Thank you @jamespaden, since I will be working with both I will do a better research!

Comment: That's amazing! I was investigating the issue, working with Paged.js generated content. @Lila, your solution matches in my case also

Comment: Love how easy it was to solve this issue! Thanks for the tip.