# HTML table tfoot element bottom of the every page while creating pdf with itext7 html2pdf

Tags: c#, html, css, pdf, itext7

I am creating pdf using c# with the help of itext7 html2pdf nuget package.

My html is nearly as the same as:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
           no problem with thead.
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           huge content continues for pages
           and also another tables inside of it.
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
           i want this to be on bottom of every page
           there is a table but it is not the case i think, content is not big
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
```

i am using this css for pagination:

```
    table {
        page-break-inside: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    tr {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
        page-break-after: auto;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group;
    }

    tfoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
    }
```

I tried and searhed on stackoverflow almost every thing but there is no result.

Currently on pagination there is a gap between tfoot and end of the page, but i want this gap between tbody and tfoot elements.

How can i achive this behaviour?

note: some of my tries gave correct behavior on browser print mode but not pdf creation. What i have tried for example: position:fixed; bottom:0; for tfoot element.

Edit: screen shot of pdf added.

[image: sample pdf]

Comment: Please attach your code and visual illustration explaining of what you are getting now and what you intend to get

Comment: I added sample pdf screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have continued to search and solved it with mixing up 2 stackoverflow answer.

First one: [about putting footer to right place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57580219/itext7-html2pdf-fixed-footer-using-css)

second one: [about placing footer to every page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56311521/running-footer-elementfooter-in-paged-media-appear-only-in-last-page)

To conclude, my codes like this in summary:

```
<style>
    #footer {
        position: running(footer);
    }

    @page{
        @bottom-center {
            content: element(footer);
        }
    }

    /* other css for pagination and style */
</style>

<body>
    <!-- This footer div must be the first element of the body, this is important. Otherwise it appears only on the last page! --> 
    <div id="footer">
    Footer content
    </div>
    
    <!-- table without tfoot element! -->
    <table>
        <thead>
            header content
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            body content
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```